# Почему не работает передача емейла из формы?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Почему не передаются данные из формы ?Нужно что бы при нажатии на кнопку save me в появляющемся окне (место для текста выделено красным ) появлялось следующее

message.textContent = 'Адрес ' + email.value + ' добавлен';

Не могу понять что не так сделал ?
Все остальное работает

```
  https://codepen.io/sergey112/pen/GRZmRYj
```

```js
let email = document.querySelector('.newslatter__content-email-place');
let message = document.querySelector('.newslatter-form__content-text');
const newslatterForm = document.querySelector('.newslatter-form');
const sendForm = document.querySelector('.newslatter__content-email-button');

function togglenewslatterForm(newslatterForm) {
    newslatterForm.classList.toggle('newslatter-form_active');
    if (newslatterForm.classList.contains('newslatter-form_active')) {
        document.addEventListener('keydown', closeNewsLatterFormEscape);
    } else {
        document.removeEventListener('keydown', closeNewsLatterFormEscape);
    }
}

const closeNewsLatterFormEscape = (evt) => {
    const activeNewsLatterForm = document.querySelector('.newslatter-form_active')
    if (evt.key === "Escape") {
        activeNewsLatterForm.classList.remove('newslatter-form_active');
        document.removeEventListener('keydown', closeNewsLatterFormEscape);
    }

}
sendForm.addEventListener('click', () => {
    togglenewslatterForm(newslatterForm);

});

newslatterForm.onsubmit = function(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
   
    message.textContent = 'Адрес ' + email.value + ' добавлен';
};
```

```css
 .newslatter-form {
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .05);
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        visibility: hidden;
        opacity: 0;
    }
    
    .newslatter-form_active {
        visibility: visible;
        opacity: 1;
    }
    
    .newslatter-form__content {
        width: 600px;
        height: 450px;
        border: 1px red solid;
        background-color: #FFFFFF;
        color: black;
    }

.newslatter-form__content-text{
  border:1px red solid;
  width:300px;
  height:20px;
  margin:200px auto;
  
}
```

```html
<form action="#" class="newslatter__content-email">
                    <input type="email" name="place-link" id="linkinput" placeholder="Email address" class="newslatter__content-email-place" required>
                    <button type="submit" class="newslatter__content-email-button">Save me</button>
                </form>

<div class="newslatter-form">
            <div class="newslatter-form__content">
                <h2 class="newslatter-form__content-text"></h2>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Инпут находится в другом родителе.

---

```
document.querySelector(".newslatter__content-email").addEventListener("submit", function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  message.textContent = 'Адрес ' + email.value + ' добавлен';
});
```

Comment: @ Igor К сожалению не могу понять как исправить

Comment: Все  , разобрался